# Dynamic Access Control for entities in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I try to manage the access rights for users to edit or view different articles.

Articles can be created dynamically and the rights should be editable for every article.

In my case, I have a User object and multiple other objects (Article, and more...).

I need to check if a User can read or write any kind of object.

I actually see there is a method Voters, but they only can manage User groups?

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

A Voter can decide almost anything - usually it's based on a user's permission, but it doesn't have to be - I've used one as a 'feature flag' check, with a value fetched from a configuration, or database entry to show something - or not, as an example.

The [page on voters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html#setup-checking-for-access-in-a-controller) has an example on viewing, or editing a database record (a `Post` entity, via a `$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('edit', $post);`.

In your instance, the voter would be passed the 'attribute', the object (Article, etc) you want to check on, and gets the current user from a service. If that user has the appropriate permission to read/edit/delete the Article or other object, it returns true.

Comment: did you add to users entity attributes (read, edit, delete) or where did you save this information in database?